# Error Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

When I'm running this it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Canvas: `<canvas id="c" style="background-color: black;">`

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var grid = [];

for (var j = 0; j < c.height; j++) {
  grid.push([]);
  for (var i = 0; i < c.width; i++) {
    grid[j].push(0);
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (var j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = (grid[i][j] == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';
      ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
    }
  }
}

//setInterval(draw, 10);
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" style="background-color: black;">
```

Comment: I would try and add a few console.log statements throughout your code. This way you can understand which code is working as expected, and where the error is happening.

Comment: The "rows" use index `j` and the "columns" use index `i` -> `grid[i][j]` should be `grid[j][i]`.

Comment: What line was the error pointing to? that should help you.

Comment: @Andreas Omg! Such a simple error, i overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `grid.length` instead `grid[0].length` in inner for loop.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var grid = [];

for (var j = 0; j < c.height; j++) {
  grid.push([]);
  for (var i = 0; i < c.width; i++) {
    grid[j].push(0);
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (var j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = (grid[i][j] == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';
      ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
    }
  }
}

//setInterval(draw, 10);
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" style="background-color: black;">
```